# Javascript, convert an array of double into an array of pair of doubles

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose that you have an array of doubles in Javascript:

```
double_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What is the most efficient way to convert it into an array of arrays with 2 doubles like above:

```
double_arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
```

Comment: I'm really curious about your definition of _"double"_...

Comment: @Andreas Numbers

Comment: get answer here, its same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate skipping one index in each iteration, like this:

```js
const double_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < double_arr.length; i += 2)
  result.push([ double_arr[i], double_arr[i+1] ]);
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @heisenberg If you think a downvote is _"mean"_ than you haven't understood the concept of downvotes. A downvote indicates a problem with the question/answer. Nothing more, nothing less. The DV on this answer is unnecessary. But this answer should not have been added in the first place as there's a valid dupe target (with at least one of the answers being the same as this one).